# How to call an Object's Method from another class without creating a sub-class and/or inheriting class?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, methods

I've been learning basic code at a very beginner level. Now I'm finally starting to dabble in actually writing simple programs, and got really stuck.

- I'm writing a simple a program that consists of two classes; People,
  MainPage.
- Once the program runs, the method `openApp()` is called in main method from (MainPage Class).

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        openApp();                
  }
  ```
- Next, when the `openApp()` is called, the user has three menus to choose to go to that are selected by entering the corresponding number

  *i.e. 1 = Newsfeed, 2 = Profile or 3 = Friends.*

public class MainPage {

```
public static void openApp() {


    System.out.println("Welcome to App!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To Select Option for:");
    System.out.println("Newsfeed : 1");
    System.out.println("Profile :  2");
    System.out.println("Friends :  3");
    System.out.println("Enter corresponding number: ");
    int optionSelected = input.nextInt();

    switch (optionSelected) { 

    case 1: System.out.println("NewsFeed");
             break;
    case 2:  System.out.println("Profile");
             break;
    case 3:  System.out.println("Friends");
        break;

        if (optionSelected == 3) {
            people.friend();// Is it possible to write: friend() from "People" Class without extending to People Class
                    }

    }
}
```

- If User selects "friends" then the program calls a method *from*
  People Class called `friend(People name)` *in* MainPage class that prints out **people** object's friends.

My Attempt:

```
  if (optionSelected == 3) {
        people.friend();
                }
```

The Error I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       people cannot be resolved

**Problem is I don't want to extend People Class in MainPage and inherit all it's methods, yet I still want to call an Object method from People Class to print *people* object's friends.**

*Note: just in case anyone would want to look at the `friend(People people)`  method that is located in the People class:*

```
public void friend(People people) {
    System.out.println(people.friend);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question format.

You can declare an `Object` of type `People`, and use that.

**Example**

```
public class MainPage
{
    People people = new People();

    // .. Some code.

    if(optionSelected == 3) {
        people.friend();
    } 
}
```

**Explanation**

Your `friend` method is an `instance method`. This means that in order to access it, you need to have an instance of the object created. This is done with the `new` keyword. Secondly, unless `People` is some form of utility class, then your `friend` method should probably read more like:

```
 public void friend()
 {
     System.out.println(this.friend);
 }
```

And for the sake of good code design, remember that your `MainPage` class is outputting to the user, so you should `return` the value rather than print it. Secondly, you should conform to good naming standards, and in `Java` we use the `get` prefix when getting a class member.

```
public void getFriend()
{
    return this.friend;
}
```

and in the `MainPage` class, you should print this.

```
if(optionSelected == 3)
{
   System.out.println(people.getFriend());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer, Christopher! Really appreciated :)